# JOI2007 A問題で、アルゴリズムは合っていそうなのにテストケースの半分が通らない

Tags: c++

与えられた数列の部分和の最大値を求める問題でC++のqueueを使ったのですがACしません。元サイトのテストケースでは同じ出力が出るのですがatcoderでは半分がWAとなってしまいます。

[JOI2007A](https://www.ioi-jp.org/joi/2006/2007-ho-prob_and_sol/2007-ho.pdf#page=2)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
#define rep(i, n) for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
#define reps(i, n) for(int i=1; i <= n; i++)
#define INF 1e9
#define ALL(v) v.begin(), v.end()

using namespace std;
using ll=long long;


int main() {
  int n,k;
  cin >> n >> k;
  ll s=0;
  ll a;

  queue<int> q;
  rep(i,k){
    cin >> a;
    s += a;
    q.push(a);
  }

  ll ans=s;
  if(n>k){
    rep(i,n-k){
      cin >> a;
      s -= q.front();
      q.pop();
      s+=a;
      q.push(a);
      ans=max(ans,s);
    }
  }
  cout << ans;
}
```

Comment: 解答のチェックがどの様に行われているのか分かりませんので何とも言えませんが、最大値の出力が `cout << ans;` となっていて改行コードを出力していない点が少し気になります。

Comment: 改行を促されていない場合は今まで問題ありませんでした。一部ACとなっているので改行ミスの場合は全部WAとなると思います。

Comment: atcoderのどのテストかわかるとすぐ試せるのですが。問題へのリンクを追加してください。

Comment: https://atcoder.jp/contests/joi2007ho/tasks/joi2007ho_a
こちらになります！

Answer (score 2):

metropolisさんも指摘している通り改行(std::endl)がないのが問題のように思われます。
std::endlには改行のみではなくstd::basic_stream::flush()を呼び出す機能もあります。
これを呼ばないと出力データがバッファにため込まれたまま標準出力に書き込まれません。
そのため、プログラムがflushするかどうかはバッファに依存するので、運次第ではときどきWAとなるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: `std::cout` はプログラム終了時点で `flush()` されます ISO/IEC 14882:1998 18.3 (209) ので、そういう挙動をするのは規格違反な処理系のみってことになりそうです。まあオイラも改行を出力してないのが WA 原因であるに１票っす。

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事ACしました！！問題文になくても改行したほうがいいのですね